# Cross compilation : jdk1.6 on jdk 1.7

Tags: java, ant, cross-compiling

I Have a java source code written on jdk7. and have jdk7 and jre7 on my machine.

Now i need to compile this code with compiler jdk1.6 using ANT.

So I tried to add the following lines in my project build.xml.

```
<target name="compile">
<javac target="1.6" srcdir="src"/>
</target>
```

Is this enough ? Or do i have to add bootclasspath?
If yes, please specify syntax with which i can add in build file

Answer (score 3):

That might not be enough.

First of all, besides setting `target` to `1.6`, you should also set `source` to `1.6`:

```
<javac source="1.6" target="1.6" srcdir="src">
```

to let the Java compiler know that it should interpret your code as 1.6-compatible source code.

But a bigger problem is that this does not prevent you from using classes, interfaces and methods which are new in the Java 7 standard library. If you use Java 7-only classes, interfaces or methods, it will compile, but you'll get errors like `NoSuchMethodError` when you run it on Java 6 and you're calling a method that didn't exist in Java 6.

The safest way to ensure that your code is compatible with Java 6 is installing JDK 6 and using that to compile your code. (Note: There's no problem with having multiple versions of the JDK installed on your machine, just install them in different directories).

Comment: Ok I will go for safe way !
1. Will include jdk1.6 
2. set its path to environment variable
3. its a project , so will set <javac source="1.6" target="1.6" srcdir="src"> in the ant buildxml
4.When i try building jar , do i have to specify what jdk and all..?

Comment: Thanks a lot Jesper ! that indeed helped